# Key error when clicking on /viewcart in python flask

Tags: python, flask, session

I am working with sessions. When the user clicks on /viewtask I want it to validate if there is an email in session. If there isnt my program should redirect the user to the login page.
If there is then I want the user to view the cart. When I test this I get a **'Key error : Email'**

I think its ignoring the if statement.
I have no issue assigning a session something but I keep getting errors when checking the session.

App.py

```
@app.route("/viewcart")
def viewcart():
if session.get("Email") == None:
    return redirect(url_for(loginform))
else:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Email = '" + session['Email'] + "'")
    UserID = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute("SELECT Products.Name , Products.Price , Products.Image , Cart.Size FROM Products,Cart WHERE Products.ID == Cart.ProductID AND Cart.UserID == ?",(str(UserID)))
    products = c.fetchall()

    
    return render_template("cart.html",products = products)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you really have in `session`.

Comment: you put code with wrong intentation - and this can change everything. Always put code with correct indentations.